# onclick set php session to keep checkbox checked. On uncheck end session

Tags: php, javascript

This is my form :

```
<input type="checkbox" name="dept" value="sales" <?php if(isset($_POST['sales'])) echo "checked='checked'"; ?> onclick="this.form.submit();" /><br />
```

When i click the checkbox, the page is refreshed with the ?dept=sales in the URL. Just as i want it to be. But the checkbox is unchecked. I want the checkbox to be checked. And when the checkbox is unchecked i want the ?dept=sales to be removed from teh URL.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first check your check box name, It's dept but you fetch from sales $_POST, another hint is that if your request is shown on the url then it's get not post, If you want to remove parameter from your url add method="post" to your form, At last your code should be like this:

```
<form action="your action here" method="post">
<input type="checkbox" name="sales" value="sales" <?php if(isset($_POST['sales'])) echo "checked='checked'"; ?> onclick="this.form.submit();" /><br />
</form>
```

Comment: i changed it to GET. I am able to get the reults in 1 checkbox. How do i go about it if i have multiple checkboxes ?

Comment: For this you should write your checkbox tags and name them and when you check them write multiple if statements like:
`<input type="checkbox" name="check1" value="something"/>`
`<input type="checkbox" name="check2" value="something/>`
`<?php`
`if(isset($_POST["check1"])){ your command ...}`
`if(isset($_POST["check2"])){ your command ...}`
`?>`

Comment: But this will create multiple checkboxes with different names [as you mentioned name="check1" and name="check2"]. I wont be able to pass checked data in an array in php.

Comment: You don't need to pass theme in an array. When you check a checkbox value of checkbox will be send If not the value won't be send.If you have multiple checkboxes then if you checked all of them their value will be store in $_GET or $_POST

Comment: i created the checkboxes and the php script. But i want to execute the php script when the checkbox is checked and uncheck the checkbox and kill the session for the value of that checkbox

Comment: Tell me this: Do you want send just one value with checkboxes?

Comment: No, i want to send multiple values. If only 1 chkbox is checked, send only 1 value, if multiple are selected, send multiple values.

Comment: Ok, so you should clear onClick attribute in your Input tag. Because with this attribute form will submit on checked or uncheck of each checkbox, make a form with a submit button, then when the form values sent to the server side put $_POST indices into if - else block and do whatever you need. like this:
The HTML FORM
`<input type="checkbox" name="check1" />`
`<input type="checkbox" name="check2" />`
`<input type="checkbox" name="check3" />`
PHP Code:
`<?php`
`if(isset($_POST["check1"])){ command }`
`2lse if(isset($_POST["check2"])){ command }`
`else if(isset($_POST["check2"])){ command }`

Comment: I think m nt stating my problem properly. I am able to get the array in php and run my code, its only the client side scripting, i.e. the checkbox thing i am not able to achieve. I want the php code to be excecuted when the checkbox is checked without having to click any submit button. Then i want the checkbox to be checked on the page refresh. When i uncheck the checkbox, i want the php code to be excecuted again without clicking any submit button. And when the page is refreshed, the checkbox to be unchecked. thx.

Comment: something like a validate function maybe

Comment: Ok If this is so, why don't you use ajax? Because refreshing a page again and again is not an user friendly way.huh?

Comment: I want to learn how to do this in javascript first. Please help me in this without using Ajax

Comment: You can't run a php script by using client side code without ajax my friend. But if you want email me your question completely, I will answer If I can.

Comment: I am sorry .. I am unable to IM u or email u from ur profile. :(

Comment: never mind buddy, my email is bhtk.2005@gmail.com or bhk_2005@gmail.com

Comment: Emailed u. Thanks a million bro!

Answer (score 5):

Your checkbox's *name* is `dept`, not `sales`. The *value* of your checkbox is `sales`. This means that if you want to access the value of your checkbox, you will need to access it via `$_POST['dept']`, not `$_POST['sales']`. If your form method isn't declared as `method="post"`, use `$_GET['dept']` instead of `$_POST['dept']`.

Comment: Since he has ?dept=sales, $_REQUEST['dept'] is even better!

Comment: Thank you. Your suggestion is a great help. I am able to accomplish that for 1 checkbox. How do i go about multiple ?  Like for the following 2 checkboxes, when i try, both the checkboxes are checked if i select only 1.

Comment: <input type="checkbox" name="dept" value="sales" <?php if(isset($_GET['dept'])) echo "checked='checked'"; ?> onclick="this.form.submit();" /> Sales<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="dept" value="IT" <?php if(isset($_GET['dept'])) echo "checked='checked'"; ?> onclick="this.form.submit();" /> IT <br />

Comment: Look up examples of how to use checkbox arrays with PHP.

Comment: i can work with checkbox arrays in php, but the client side scripting is scary fr me. I want the box to be checked/unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

You're checking for an input with the name "sales" change $_POST['sales'] to $_POST['dept'] that'll work :)

Answer (score 0):

**Submit** the `form` only when the **checked property true** like,

```
<input type="checkbox" name="dept" value="sales" 
     <?php if($_REQUEST['dept']=='sales')) echo "checked='checked'"; ?> 
     onclick="if(this.checked==true) this.form.submit();" /><br />
```